# How is Jmock used with HttpSession and HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmock

I am new to jmock and trying to mock an HttpSession. I am getting:

java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: httpServletRequest.getSession()
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?

the test method:

@Test

```
public void testDoAuthorization(){

    final HttpServletRequest request = context.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
       one(request).getSession(true); will(returnValue(session));
   }});

    assertTrue(dwnLoadCel.doAuthorization(session));
}
```

I have done a bit of searching and it isn't clear to me still how this is done. Feels like I am missing some small piece. Anyone with experience in this can just point me in the right direction.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mock the request object.  Since the method you're testing (`dwnLoadCel.doAuthorization()`) only depends on an `HttpSession` object, that is what you should mock.  So your code would look like this:

```
public void testDoAuthorization(){
    final HttpSession session = context.mock(HttpSession.class);

    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
        // ???
    }});

    assertTrue(dwnLoadCel.doAuthorization(session));
```

}

The question becomes: what do you expect the SUT to actually *do* with the session object?  You need to express in your expectations the calls to `session` and their corresponding return values that are supposed to result in `doAuthorization` returning `true`.

Comment: this helped me in the right direction. I needed to just use the httpssession and upgrade my version of hamcrest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tell the JMock context how many times you expect the method to be called before you actually go ahead and call it.

```
final HttpServletRequest request = context.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

context.checking(new Expectations(){{
  one(request).getSession(true); will(returnValue(session));
}});

final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

I'm not super familiar with JMock but do you actually care in your `dwnLoadCel` unit test how many times certain methods in the mocked object are called? Or are you just trying to test your class that depends on a HttpSession without an actual Session? If it's the latter than I think that JMock is overkill for you.

You might want to look into either creating a class that implements the `HttpSession` interface yourself for the purposes of unit testing only (a stub), and running your tests off of that, or you should take a look at `dwnLoadCel` and determine if it *really* needs to have a reference to the HttpSession, or if it just needs some properties within the HttpSession. Refactor `dwnLoadCel` to only depend on what it actually needs (a `Map` or a certain parameter value within the Session object) - this will make your unit test easier (the dependency on the servlet container goes bye-bye).

I think that you have some level of dependency injection in your class being tested already, but you might be dependent on too broad of an object. [The Google Test Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/) has had [a lot](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/10/dependency-injection-myth-reference.html) [of excellent](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/) [articles](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/10/where-have-all-the-new-operators-gone/) on DI lately that you might find useful (I sure have).

Comment: good answer. After reviewing the problem it seems reasonable to take a look at the class that dwnLoadCel uses for doAuthorization. Maybe refactoring that is an option.

Comment: For the record, there's the 'allowing()' clause in jMock which effectively stubs a call. It allows the call to be made as many times as you like. We usually 'allow' queries which do not change the state of the collaborator